# sdkmanager error (Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest)

Tags: flutter

when I try installing build tools using sdkmanager on window using this command below

```
C:\all-things-flutter\flutter-installation\android\cmdline-tools\bin>sdkmanager.bat "build-tools;30.0.0" --sdk_root=../
```

I keep getting this error

```
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
```

please this is not a duplicate question, cus I didn't find the answer I needed.

this has been bugging me for days so how can I get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I could not get an answer after 8 months, I have decided to share how I did it and other kinds of solutions people have suggested but not from here.

**How i did it**
I downloaded android studio (even tho i was not going to use it), then i use android studio to download the recommended SDK i will need, after that i added the SDK folder path to my system variable, that way i can continue the flutter installation and run flutter doctor, which did ditect my SDK path.

**Other people Suggesttion**
From my research online, I saw people saying that you need a much slower internet connection because if your internet connection is faster, it will skip some downloads, which can cause the SDK to not work well.

but my response to that is "yer good luck with that".